# css margin-left not running on safari

Tags: css, safari, webkit

I am having trouble with using margin-left with safari

here's my css

```
<style>
            .profile___options {
                position: absolute; width: 828px; height: 45px; border-top: 1.1px solid #eee; margin-top: 97px; margin-left: 282px;
            }

            .profile___options ul {
                float: right;
                margin-right: 329px;
            }

            .profile___options ul li {
                border-right: 1px solid #e9eaed;
                float: left;
                font-size: 15px;
                font-weight: 600;
                height: 43px;
                position: relative;
                list-style: none;
                vertical-align: middle;
                white-space: nowrap;
                cursor: pointer;
                padding: 16px;
                color: #365899;
                padding: -1px;
            }
        </style>
```

and here's my html code

```
    <div class="profile___options">
            <div class="fsaafFDSA__">
                <div class="223__adAas">
                    <div class="profile___options_inner">
                        <ul class="user_ul">
                            <li>
                                <a class="questions_link">Questions</a>
                            </li>


                            <div class="user_bookmark" style="
                            position: absolute;
                            margin-left: -121px;">

                            </div>

                            <li style="width: 136px;" class="followerLink">
                                <!--<span class="badge badge-danger" style="color: #fff;background-color: #dc3545;width: 19px;margin-top: 5px;position: absolute;margin-left: -7px;">3</span>-->
                                Followers
                            </li>


                            <li style="width: 136px;" class="followingLink">
                                <!--<span class="badge badge-danger" style="color: #fff;background-color: #dc3545;width: 19px;margin-top: 5px;position: absolute;margin-left: -7px;">3</span>-->
                                Following 
                            </li>


                        </ul>


                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

and here's the result on chrome

[result on chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2rlq.png)

and here's the result on safari

[Result on safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rucl.png)

what I am trying to accomplish is to keep the bottom navbar with the black outline to be aligned at the same place on both browsers

Thanks,

Arnav

Comment: I think it's a positioning problem. can you update your full HTML and CSS code?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
-webkit-margin-start (left)
-webkit-margin-end (right)
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/StandardCSSProperties.html

Hope I helped.